# Memory is still allocated but not used?

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

I've got this long path traversal query:

```
match path=(n)-[:CFG|DFG|IDFG*bfs..1000]->(m)-[:CFG|DFG|IDFG*bfs..1000]->(k) 
return nodes(path) as n, relationships(path) as r 
limit 10;
```

The query aborts with the memory limit exceeded. Memgraph keeps running but even though the query was aborted, the memory isn't getting freed (usual memory usage is 1GB, and after the path query it stays on 12GB)
Or is it just, that the memory is still allocated but not used?

Answer (score 0):

You can free up memory by using the following query:

```
FREE MEMORY;
```

You can also inspect memory usage with:

```
SHOW STORAGE INFO;
```

[Here](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/memory-control) is a more detailed explanation if you'd like to know more